# Which features to use while detecting outliers in data

Tags: feature-selection, outliers

I have a dataset which contain many continuous and categorical features and categorical output. Not all the features are correlated with output, so I took a subset of features - only those which show significant correlation with output.

My question is - While doing outlier detection, should I use all features, or only those which I took as subset (correlated with output)? How will these two approaches affect the results?

Comment: If the output is categorical, how are other variables "correlated" with it?  Also, removing outliers could change correlation  (or whatever measure you used).

Comment: @PeterFlom I used chisq and Cramer's V to determine the strength of association between categorical features and output. By correlation here I mean strength of association.

Comment: @PeterFlom Also, I am not measuring strength of association after removing outliers, I am doing outlier detection after measuring strength of association. (I don't know if its the right order of doing it.)

Comment: Why are you trying to detect outliers? What's the purpose of your overall analysis?

Comment: @PeterFlom I am creating a machine learning model on the data. I created many and got nearly 70% accuracy in all of them, so I thought may be because of outliers I am not getting more accuracy.